# How to pass parameters from renderer, through preload, to main and then return the response back to renderer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am very new to Electron and I have been developing with context isolation set to false and node intergration set to true. I am now changing my application to the default window settings (context isolation set to true and node integration set to false) but I am having trouble calling a https get request from the main (because I cannot figure out how to pass parameters through).

Essentially all I want is to be able to use node's https module to do an api call and get the data back to the renderer.

Sorry for the simple error, I am very new to nodejs and electron.

I will link the relevant parts of my code below:

preload.js

```
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

let indexBridge = {
    getHttpReq: async (addressInput,startDateEpoch,endDateEpoch) => {
        var result = await ipcRenderer.invoke("getHttpReq")
    }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("indexBridge", indexBridge);
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require("path");
const https = require('https');
const createWindow = () =>{
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 625,
        width: 1000,
        webPreferences: {
            //nodeIntegration: true,
            //contextIsolation: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        }
    });
    win.loadFile("index.html");
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
};

ipcMain.handle("getHttpReq", (originalWallet,startDateEpoch,endDateEpoch) =>{
    console.log("Here are the parameters. Original wallet:" + originalWallet+" start epoch: "+startDateEpoch+" end epoch: "+endDateEpoch);

    const request = https.request()
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
        https.get('https://public-api.solscan.io/account/exportTransactions?account=' + originalWallet + '&type=soltransfer&fromTime=' + startDateEpoch + '&toTime=' + endDateEpoch, (resp) => {
           let data = '';
   
           // A chunk of data has been received.
           resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
               data += chunk;
           });
           //Print status code to console
           console.log("Status code from solscan" + resp.statusCode);
           // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
           resp.on('end', () => {
               if (resp.statusCode != 200) {
                   console.log("Error details from Solscan: " + data);
               }
               //console.log("Raw api data: \n\n" + data);
               //ORIGINAL:
               //var finalArrayToPass = csvToArray(data,originalWallet);
               console.log(data);
               resolve(data);
           });
   
       }).on("error", (err) => {
           reject({message: "rejected!"});
           console.log("Error: " + err.message);
       });
   });
})
```

renderer.js

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", processInputWallet);

function getHttpReq(addressInput,startDateEpoch,endDateEpoch){
    window.indexBridge.getHttpReq(addressInput,startDateEpoch,endDateEpoch);
}

async function processInputWallet() {
    //Get input values from HTML input
    var addressInput = document.getElementById("solAddress").value;
    var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
    var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);
    //Converts traditional date input to epoch which is recognised by the Solscan API
    var startDateEpoch = startDate.getTime() / 1000;
    var endDateEpoch = endDate.getTime() / 1000;
    var result = getHttpReq(addressInput,startDateEpoch,endDateEpoch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a live API ([Solscan -> Account -> exportTransactions](https://public-api.solscan.io/docs/#/Account/get_account_exportTransactions)) one cannot properly test for the desired response without valid arguments.

Placing that aside, you appear to be missing a `return` statement in your `preload` script.

---

`preload.js` (main process)

For simplicity, I have combined your API key `indexBridge` and associated API `getHttpReq` directly into the Electron [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) call.

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'indexBridge', {
        // From render to main and back again
        getHttpReq: (data) => {
            return ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data);
        }
    }
);

/**
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.indexBridge.apiName(data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { return ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await myPromise(data).then((result) => { return result; })
 *          });
 *
 * Main:    function myPromise(data) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }; )};
 *
 */
```

---

`main.js` (main process)

Within this `main.js` file, I have created a `exportTransactions` function to provide a bit of separation of your promise from the [ipcMain.handle(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) call.

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');
const nodeHttps = require('https');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 1000,
        height: 625,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
    return await exportTransactions(data)
        .then((result) => { return result; })
})

function exportTransactions(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = 'https://public-api.solscan.io/account/exportTransactions?' +
            'account=' + input.addressInput +
            '&type=soltransfer&fromTime=' + input.startDateEpoch +
            '&toTime=' + input.endDateEpoch;

        nodeHttps.get(url, (res) => {
            let data = '';

            // A chunk of data has been received.
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            // Print status code to console
            console.log('Status code from solscan: ' + res.statusCode);

            // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
            res.on('end', () => {
                if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                    console.log('Error details from Solscan: ' + data);
                }

                // console.log("Raw api data: \n\n" + data);

                // ORIGINAL:
                // let finalArrayToPass = csvToArray(data, originalWallet);
                // console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
            });

        }).on('error', (err) => {
            reject({message: 'rejected!'});
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    });
}
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

I have taken the liberty of adding some html code with your `renderer.js` file for a complete working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for="addressInput">Address: </label>
        <input type="text" id="addressInput" value="unknown">

        <br><br>

        <label for="startDate">Start Date: </label>
        <input type="date" id="startDate" value="2023-01-01">

        <br><br>

        <label for="endDate">End Date: </label>
        <input type="date" id="endDate" value="2023-01-31">

        <br><br>

        <input type="button" id="process" value="Process">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('process').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Get input values from HTML input
            let addressInput = document.getElementById('addressInput').value;
            let startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value);
            let endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value);

            // Converts traditional date input to epoch which is recognised by the Solscan API
            let startDateEpoch = startDate.getTime() / 1000;
            let endDateEpoch = endDate.getTime() / 1000;

            let data = {
                'addressInput': addressInput,
                'startDateEpoch': startDateEpoch,
                'endDateEpoch': endDateEpoch
            }

            window.indexBridge.getHttpReq(data)
                .then((result) => { console.log(result); });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```